# Laravel hasMany to Belongs to returns undefined

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I know this has been asked before but specific to my case I could't find an answer that worked.

Currently I have two models.
App\JobStatus
App\Customer

In model App\JobStatus I have this:

```
public function customer()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Customer');
}
```

In model App\Customer I have this:

```
public function jobs()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\JobStatus', 'customer_id');
}
```

'customer_id' is the foreign key.  I then try to access customer from Jobstatus in my controller like so:

```
$testMePlease = JobStatus::first()->where('qb', '=', 1);
$testMePlease->customer;
```

I have attempted to dd this.  To put it in foreach loop.  I've also tried $testMePlease->customer->customer_name.  Customer_name being a column in the table and I get back the same error: "Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$customer"

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: This is backwards: `::first()->where('qb', '=', 1);`, should be `::where('qb', '=', 1)->first();` That should work, unless `$testMePlease` ends up being `null`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to change

```
$testMePlease = JobStatus::first()->where('qb', '=', 1);
```

To

```
$testMePlease = JobStatus::where('qb', '=', 1)->first();
```